# Get Shared Preference in second activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to reuse my shared preference obtain in MainActivity in my SecondActivity. 
The customer should have a URL and it is recorded in the sharedpreference, and I wish we could reuse this stored in my SecondActivity to put it in a webview (of the form eg http: //MySharedPreferenceURL/ mypage <- mypage is static, and is dynamic MySharedPreferenceURL

My code of MainActivity is :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        loadSavedPreferences();
    }

    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Some name", 0);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");
        if (checkBoxValue) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        editText.setText(name);
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Some name", 0);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
        if (checkBox.isChecked())
            savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

        finish();
    }

}
```

Edit :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        loadSavedPreferences();
    }

    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");
        if (checkBoxValue) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        editText.setText(name);
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
        if (checkBox.isChecked())
            savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

        finish();
    }

}
```

And , I don't know how to display in my SecondActivty, can you help me and explain me

Comment: @PedroHawk answered the question, if you want to use SharedPreferences. But the better communication between Activities is through [Intent objects](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`, why dont you try

```
SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreferences("Some name", 0);
Editor editor = sp.edit();´
(...)
```

that `"some name"` will be the name of the file where you store the data. (if dont exist, it will create automatically)

On other activities, you just need to call `SharedPreference` pointing to **same name**.

**SAMPLE:**

one activity:

```
    public class Activity1 extends Activity
    {
       (...)
       SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("my_profile", 0);
       Editor editor = sp.edit();
       editor.putString("Name", "PedroHawk");
       editor.putString("Hobby", "making samples on stackoverflow");
       editor.commit();
       (...)
    }
```

Other activity:

```
    public class Activity2 extends Activity
    {
       (...)
       SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("my_profile", 0);
       String myName = sp.getString("Name", "empty");
       String myHobby = sp.getString("Hobby", "empty");
       (...)
    }
```

Comment: Hum, can you give me an example ?

Comment: So if I understand :

 `private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`
become : 

`private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getSharedPreferences("Some name", 0);`

?

Comment: forget the getdefaultsharedpreferences... check my sample

Comment: After try it, it's don't work for me ... SharedPreference isn't store :/

Comment: still with problems? check: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html